# How can I use in clause with JPQL?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I tried this code

```
   Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c where c.id in 1" );
```

but I have this error

```
 An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
    Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT c FROM Category c where c.id in 1]. 
    [31, 40] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [paragraph 10.2.5.8 of the JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_in). It should look like `where c.id in (1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the JPQL compliant examples for IN predicate from documentation.

1. select p from Payment p where type(p) in (CreditCardPayment,
   WireTransferPayment)
2. select c from Customer c where c.hqAddress.state in ('TX', 'OK',
   'LA', 'NM')
3. select c from Customer c where c.hqAddress.state in ?
4. select c from Customer c where c.hqAddress.state in (
       select dm.state
       from DeliveryMetadata dm
       where dm.salesTax is not null )

Option 2. seems what you are looking for, you can try below query.

> SELECT c FROM Category c where c.id in (1)

But if you are giving constant single value, why you aren't using `=` instead.